# Not showing the right set of linearly independent eigenvectors

Tags: soft-question, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

I am using matlab R2013a.

Consider the matrix 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$ 
Clearly, it's rank is 2; so nulity is 3. But while computing all its eigenvectors, it's showing as if it has only one linearly independent eigenvector. Theoretically, it has 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
as three linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the $0$ eigenvalue.

So why is it so with the command [vA,d]=eig(A)?

Where is the mistake?
Or

Whether matlab is showing wrong result here?

Comment: @Moo Yes. I mean the right eigenvectors only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happens here but if you use `null(mA)` and `svd(mA)` results seems to be more reasonable.